# Bit wise operator

Tags: optimization, bit-manipulation

Take any number of following type 2, 2^2(=4), 2^3(=8) , 16 ,32 , 64 ...

If we will make ORing (|) of two numbers like

```
2| 4 = xyz 
0010 | 0100 = 0110
```

then for checking this whether this number xyz contains any of the given numbers we make ANDing of xyz with that number and if we get that number again we can say it contains that number

```
0110 & 0010 = 0010
```

can we use this property for optimizing our code ? 
or in any other practical solution ?

Comment: What kind of optimization are you talking about?  Are you just asking if there's any real-world use for the bitwise operators?

Comment: we have used it in our own framework for adding and checking of already existing events . This is one scenario of using this feature in real world programming . This would be very much faster then making comparison . So can you suggest other cases where i can use this features ?

Comment: You can use this hammer everywhere you have a nail. This is not a constructive question.

Comment: What makes you think testing a bit with `&` is faster than any other comparison?

Comment: for comparison related to any other datatype ( except bool ) you need to make comparison with that data type and obviously it is costlier then bitwise operator

Comment: and for storing some data you also need to have something like array or list then you also need to do look up in this data structure . It will add more cost .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not quite the same thing, but another "practical solution" using bit-wise operators is  using them to avoid branching.

Example:

```
if(input < B)
    output = Up;
else if(input > A)
    output = Down;
```

can be replaced with bit-wise operations with something like:

```
output = ~(!(input < B) * -1) & Up | ~(!(input > A) * -1) & Down;
```

In my case, I run lines like this many millions of times a day so the benefit of the small decrease in time they take to run outweighs the time needed to code something a little more complex like this instead of a simple if/else if to avoid branching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that kind of trick is used in enumerated flags.

For example:

```
enum Blah {

Bold = 1,
Italic = 2,
Huge = 4,
Underline = 8
}
```

If you use power-of-2 enumerations, you can then do:

```
int mystringFlags = Bold | Italic;
```

It's used quite often in many places.

Comment: That's not for optimization

Comment: @not-sehe Yea, I've changed it to "trick" already. That annoyed me too